# Foreach loop not working in Codeigniter View

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I have to list regions in two areas in single view file. Top foreach loop is working but, below foreachloop is not working.

```
<div class="wiyo_reg">
    <div class="wiyo_region_select span12">
        Choose Destination
    </div>
    <div class="wiyo_region_option_holder">
        <ul>
            <?php foreach($regions_list as $regions_list)
            {

            ?>
            <li class="wiyo_reg_li">
                <a id="wiyo_reg_id" data-value="<?php echo $regions_list -> slug; ?>" data-image="<?php echo base_url(); ?>app/resources/wiyo/img/flags/<?php echo $regions_list -> code; ?>.png" data-txt="<?php echo $regions_list -> name; ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>app/resources/wiyo/img/flags/<?php echo $regions_list -> code; ?>.png" /> <?php echo $regions_list -> slug; ?>
                </a>
            </li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="destination_error"></div>
</div>

<?php echo form_open(base_url().'index.php/bookings/search', array('id' => 'booking_regions_form', 'class' => 'booking_regions_form')); ?>
<select class="makefancy indexselect" name="booking_form_regions" style="display:none;">
    <option value="0" selected="selected" data-skip="1">Choose Destination</option><?php foreach($regions_list as $regions)
            {

            ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $regions -> slug; ?>"><?php echo $regions -> name; ?></option>

        <?php } ?>
</select>

<div class="form_label_wi_input indexform">
                <label>Departure Date</label>
    <input type="text" id="dpd6" name="booking_form_outbound_date" required="required" readonly="readonly" />
</div>

<div class="form_label_wi_input indexform">
    <label>Return Date</label>
        <input type="text" id="dpd7" name="booking_form_intbound_date" required="required" readonly="readonly" />
        </div>

<div class="form_label_wi_input">
    <input type="submit" name="submit_region" id="submit_region" class="span5 btn btn-info" value="Book" />
        </div>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

I am getting list of regions in top foreach loop but, I am getting this type of error in below foreach loop.

```
<option value="<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Trying to get property of non-object</p>
<p>Filename: partials/banner.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 74</p>

</div>"><div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Trying to get property of non-object</p>
<p>Filename: partials/banner.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 74</p>

</div></option>
```

Comment: It looks like you are redefining your `$regions_list` in the `foreach`

Comment: this isnt an answer or anything but when using inline php like that you might want to take a look at alternate syntax for control stuctures http://php.net/alternative_syntax

Comment: I am not getting it properly. How would same foreach loop works once and then not. I am stuck. Helping hands are appreciated. I am running out of deadline.

Comment: I sent other array variable from the controller with same data and then it worked. I am not getting how these error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, You have used to define `$regions_list` again in `foreach` loop `$regions_list as $regions_list`

```
foreach($regions_list as $region_list)
```

instead of

```
 foreach($regions_list as $regions_list)
```

Note: You need to replace `$regions_list ->` to `$region_list ->` in your code.

i.e. use  `<?php echo $region_list -> code; ?>`

instead of `<?php echo $regions_list -> code; ?>`

Comment: Did you replace the `$region_list -> ` in all occurrence in your code

Answer (score 0):

You reassign variable `$regions_list` to the same variable, try to use another variable like: `$region_list`
Try tho change your foreach like this:

```
<?php foreach($regions_list as $region_list){?>
     <li class="wiyo_reg_li">
        <a id="wiyo_reg_id" data-value="<?php echo $region_list -> slug; ?>" data-image="<?php echo base_url(); ?>app/resources/wiyo/img/flags/<?php echo $region_list -> code; ?>.png" data-txt="<?php echo $region_list -> name; ?>">
         <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>app/resources/wiyo/img/flags/<?php echo $region_list -> code; ?>.png" /> <?php echo $region_list -> slug; ?></a>
      </li>
 <?php } ?>
```